# Content triggers on batch actions

Tags: development, joomla-4.x

I need to trigger code when an article is moved from one category to another.

`onContentAfterSave` works fine for a single article, but what if I move articles via *Actions* -> *Batch*? Is there a trigger for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event regarding batch process:

`onBeforeBatch(BeforeBatchEvent $event)`

and the *$event* array param is passing the **source Table** and the **type** of batch operation, however I have never seen this in use in any plugin.

But what I think is useful event for you to use most probably, without knowing the full purpose, is the

`onTableAfterStore(AfterStoreEvent $event)`

This event is firing right after the batch operation and the *$event* param in this case is passing the **table** and the **result**

```
// Extract arguments
/** @var TableInterface $table */
$table  = $event['subject'];
$result = $event['result'];
```

**References** to `onBeforeBatch` event:

This Event class is defined in **src/Event/Model/** :
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/4.3-dev/libraries/src/Event/Model

According to my fast test in Joomla core **taggable plugin**, this event is firing when we do a **copy** type Batch operation on content(articles) items (so at move type operation it does not), so it ignites when we are copying items. I have not checked yet why it is that way.

The event is used in Behaviour/taggable core plugin:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.3-dev/plugins/behaviour/taggable/src/Extension/Taggable.php

And the event is property of the Admin Model in Joomla:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.3-dev/libraries/src/MVC/Model/AdminModel.php

Comment: Thanks, @Zollie.

Is there documentation for this I can look before placing questions? Or do you know this by digging into Joomla's code?

https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events does not include any reference to onBeforeBatch :(

Comment: Yes, i can link you the references: 1. This is event is part (property) of the Admin Model: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.3-dev/libraries/src/MVC/Model/AdminModel.php , so you can check and see it in the code.

Comment: Maybe i should include these links in my answer too for making it easier for anybody to get references on this event.